# How can I match on the value of a pillar attribute in a dict?

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to write a state file that matches on a pillar value, but I'm not sure how to (or if it's possible to) match on values of pillar attributes in dicts. The [salt.module.match](http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.match.html#salt.modules.match.pillar) API docs don't go into any detail about that, and none of the obvious approaches are fruitful:

```
root@ms-tapir:~ # salt clowder saltutil.refresh_pillar
clowder:
    None
root@ms-tapir:~ # salt clowder pillar.item wsgi_still
clowder:
    ----------
    wsgi_still:
        ----------
        foo:
            bar
        nginx_default:
            ----------
            directives:
                - return 444
root@ms-tapir:~ # salt clowder match.pillar 'wsgi_still["foo"]:bar'
clowder:
    False
root@ms-tapir:~ # salt clowder match.pillar "wsgi_still['foo']:bar"
clowder:
    False
root@ms-tapir:~ # salt clowder match.pillar "wsgi_still.foo:bar"
clowder:
    False
```

My attempts to debug the situation got as far as sticking a `pdb_trace()` in match.py and running salt-minion in the foreground, but that was completely useless, resulting in communication errors instead of a debug shell, presumably due to Salt's weird interaction with ØMQ. :)

To clarify, the goal would be to have something like this work in my `/srv/salt/top.sls` file:

```
base:
  'wsgi_still["foo"]:bar':
    - match: pillar
    - wsgi_distiller
```

I have confirmed that `salt clowder match.pillar "foo:bar"` works for my setup (returns `True`), when `foo: bar` in this minion's pillar.

Also, I believe this is the same problem from a different angle:

```
root@ms-tapir:~ # salt -I "foo:bar" test.ping
clowder:
    True
root@ms-tapir:~ # salt -I "wsgi_still['foo']:bar" test.ping
```

I'm just including it because 'use the -I' flag is the only suggestion I've received so far. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested dicts in pillar data are accessed in the following way:

```
salt -I "wsgi_still:foo:bar" test.ping
```

The same goes for matching in the topfile:

```
base:
  'wsgi_still:foo:bar':
    - match: pillar
    - wsgi_distiller
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. It's just delimiters all the way down. I would have never thought of that.